# Java unknown children types before runtime

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, abstract-class

I am implementing a mathematical String expression parser able to perform basic calculations (+,-,*,/) on scalar numbers and fractions.
For example: evaluating "1/3*(4/10-12/10)" returns "-4/15"

Without relying on existing math expression or fraction classes, I believe a valid mathematical expression could be:

- a scalar
- a fraction
- a basic operation (2 fractions, 2 scalars, or one of each)
- a compounded expression that will be parsed in order to determine the priority of execution of basic operations

When passed a string, the program will decide if it can be broken down into smaller expressions (compounded expression), or evaluate it if it's a basic operation.

In other words, given an expression, the program will need to decide at runtime what type of class should be used.

What is the ideal class/subclass structure and **where should the code deciding the object type reside**? In the constructor of the parent class? In a static method? In an abstract class?

*I am using Java at the moment, but the question could be language agnostic.*

Comment: Your problem doesn't appear to be about Java or even programming in general as much as it is about developing a problem domain and then developing an object model for it.  Since this is the case, this question is most likely more appropriate for a different forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like there's a hierarchy here.  `Expression` seems to be your base reference, with which it can compose of multiple `ExpressionComponent`s, being a `Scalar`, a `Fraction`, an `Operation`, and a `CompoundedExpression`.

How any of these are parsed is at your discretion, but your factories (yes, you will use factories to produce instances of anything here) will be producing concrete instances of these objects to use.  Since they're all base typed to `ExpressionComponent`, all you need to ensure is that the API for `Expression` allows you to interact with multiple `ExpressionComponent`s in an intelligent fashion.

Comment: This is very helpful, I didn't know about factories, thank you